# SpringData ReactiveMongoRepository delete by criteria

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using SpringData and ReactiveMongoRepository. I want to delete documents from Person collection whose age is 40.

```
public interface PersonRepository extends
ReactiveMongoRepository<PersonEntity, Long> {

Mono<Long> deletePersonEntitiesByAge(Long age);}
```

But It doesn't work. I set the log level of springframework.data to debug, this is the printed log..

```
o.s.d.m.r.query.MongoQueryCreator - Created query Query: { "age" : 40 }, Fields: { }, Sort: { }
```

But nothing esle.

Comment: Are you getting any error? How are you saying that the delete is unsuccessful?

Comment: Documents exist in DB

Comment: I found the solution, Mono<Void> is wrong, by replacing Mono<Long> it works! I edited the original question

Answer (score 0):

For me it works only with full entity :

```
interface GameRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Game, String> {
    @DeleteQuery(value = "{'lastUpdated': { $lt : ?0 }}")
    Flux<Game> deleteOlderThan(LocalDateTime dateTime);
}
```